# Trying to load object property via id of other object

Tags: underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am trying to loop through and lookup an id of an object to get the property of it and it's throwing: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined`

If I try to output: 
`<%- fieldInfo["firstName"].label %>` it works.

Here is my code that is throwing the error:

```
fields = "firstName, lastName";
fieldInfo = { "firstName": [
{
    "label": "Test Label",
    "name": "Test"
}
] };

<% _.each( fields.split(","), function(field){ %>
    <%- fieldInfo[field].label %>:
<% }); %>
```

I can for loop in js and it works as well but I am just learning underscore and trying to use this instead.

Comment: According to your object defiinition, it's `fieldInfo[field][0].label` and `fieldInfo["lastName"]` is undefined. Check if the object exists before acccessing the object properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fieldInfo` is an object whose only property is an array of objects, you seem to want to access `fieldInfo[field][0].label`.

Have you gone into your browsers developer tools and stepped through to see what values *are* present on each step along the way? It will make the problem (which boils down to the schema of your data) a lot clearer.